# Refreshing tab panel

Tags: angular, primeng

I have totally 3 p-tabPanel. Panel 1 and Panel 3 has built-in html and for panel 2 i am referring a component to render.

```html
<p-tabPanel header="1">
<div>

<div>
</<p-tabPanel> 

<p-tabPanel header="2">
<myComponent></<myComponent>>
</<p-tabPanel> 

<p-tabPanel header="3">
<div>

<div>
</<p-tabPanel>
```

Whenever i click "Tab 2", want to initialize a function....(`ngOnInit` method is getting called when i visit the tab for the first time)

Comment: why not you use ngOnInit() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is called only once, when the component is loaded. You can create a new function and call that on tab change

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this add *ngIf with the tabIndex value.

```
<p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="tabOption">
  <p-tabPanel header="2" >
  <myComponent *ngIf="tabOption === 2"></<myComponent>>
   </<p-tabPanel> 
....
```

This will cause to  render on active, and destroy it on inactive.